# Accessing shape in current page header

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a word document with multiple sections that contains some "separator pages," which are pages with a page-filling rectangle in the page header, so that they can use a user-defined background color.
These background colors I would like to be able to change via a macro that should be run when the user doubleclicks on a seperator page.

This kind of works (yes, I'm sure the code could be written a bit nice with a `With` block or so (I'm a C# guy, this is just a side project):

```vb
Private Sub App_WindowBeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Sel As Selection, Cancel As Boolean)    
    Dim sectionNumber As Long

    sectionNumber = ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.Selection.Information(wdActiveEndSectionNumber)

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim shapeCount As Integer
    shapeCount = ActiveDocument.Sections(sectionNumber).Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Shapes.Count
    For i = 1 To shapeCount
        ActiveDocument.Sections(sectionNumber).Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Shapes(i).Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        ActiveDocument.Sections(sectionNumber).Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Shapes(i).Fill.BackColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    Next i
End Sub
```

Of course I still need to add code to detect whether the user actually doubleclicked on a separator page etc.

But the big problem now is that the header contains the shapes for **ALL** seperator pages, not just the current one, even though they're in different sections!

And they're not even necessarily in the order they appear in the document, it seems. So how can I find the shape for the current separator page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you address the `Shapes` collection of a `Header` you will, as you've discovered, pick up all the Shapes in all the headers.

Instead, address the `Header.Range.ShapeRange` - that should return only the `Shapes` anchored in the specific Header's Range.

```
ActiveDocument.Sections(sectionNumber).Headers( _
  wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.ShapeRange(i).Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
```

Note 1: You can make your code more efficient (faster, which is especially relevant if you ever use the interop in C#) and more readable by assigning an object, rather than always fully qualifying an object hierarchy:

```
Dim hdr as Word.HeaderFooter
Set hdr = ActiveDocument.Sections(sectionNumber).Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary)
```

Note 2: if you're looking to optimize your VBA code you can use For Each...Next to loop a collection:

```
Dim shp as Word.Shape
For Each shp in hdr.Range.ShapeRange

Next
```

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for your help! Now I'm almost done. There is just one small issue: On page 2 (first page of section 2) the header is labeled "first header (section 2)" - whilst in all of the other sections, the header of the first page of a new section is just labeled "header (section X)". I have already found out that I can simply use `wdHeaderFooterFirstPage` instead of `wdHeaderFooterPrimary` for that section. However, if I do that, I seem to always get the first header, which means I would find shapes even for pages that don't contain any in their header. How can I fix this?

Comment: I mean, of course it works if I just check for "sectionNumber = 2", but I would like to not fix-code this. Maybe I can either convert that header from `wdHeaderFooterFirstPage` to `wdHeaderFooterPrimary` or so?

Comment: Not sure I follow the problem... Word has three header types: first page, normal and even pages (odd pages are normal). So often code needs to check for all three types (at least two). First Page header is what appears on the first page of every section. This should often be different (think of letter heads, for example). Maybe you can change it for that section, maybe not - I can't judge. But you CAN perform two loops, one for each header type?

Comment: I think what I'd like to do is convert that one header from "first page header" to a "normal" header. Is there a setting for that? Then I would not have to hard-code this "exception."